# @media query in custom element- only last setting takes effect

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

For some reason `@media` query is not working in my custom element....in this case the `iron-icon`. Only the the last setting takes effect, no matter what size the screen is. If I switched the order than the other last one would take effect. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
<dom-module id="portfolio-page">
  <style>
    :host[show] {
      @apply(--layout-horizontal);
      @apply(--layout-center-justified);
      height: 600px;
    }

    @media all and (max-width: 500px) {
      iron-icon { 
        --iron-icon-height: 108px;
        --iron-icon-width: 105px;
        margin-top: -21px;
      }
    }


    @media all and (min-width: 600px) {
      iron-icon { 
        --iron-icon-height: 250px;
        --iron-icon-width: 250px;
      }
    }
```

---

```
        <div class="layout horizontal center-center">
          <iron-icon icon="build"></iron-icon>
          <iron-icon icon="cloud-circle"></iron-icon>
          <iron-icon icon="http"></iron-icon>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a limitation of the style shimmer. It sucks but there is a workaround detailed in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2149

I also talk about it a bit in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VqeFubvNKw&list=PLNYkxOF6rcIDdS7HWIC_BYRunV6MHs5xo&index=4

Comment: I am using `iron-media-query` about 8 times...one for each custom element. Could this impact performance? How feasible would it be to have a global `iron-media-query` for all to custom elements to share?

Comment: Hm I imagine you could have an iron-media-query in the parent of the elements but that's not super useful for something you want to be standalone. This is a good questions for that GitHub issue. Would you mind pinging that thread so the engineer working on it can see?

Comment: should `window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1200px)").matches` also be broken? not sure if it is something I am doing wrong.